# Dataset created in DHIS2 not appearing in the dataset dropdown listing

Tags: dhis2, data

After creating a DHIS2 dataset and assigning it to the respective Org unit, when I get to the data entry app I am not able to get the created dataset on the dataset dropdown listing.

I have tried restarting my tomcat server and even invalidating and deleting cache but all seems not to work.